# Finding size of subspace

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces, geodesic

I have a finite metric space $M$ with a known number of points, and a subspace of $M$ we will call $N$. I know the average value of $d(x,N)$ for $x\in M$, where $d(x,N)=\text{inf}_{y\in N} d(x,y)$. Using this information is it possible to measure (or even estimate) the size of $N$?

What properties of $M$ and $N$ would I have to know in order to?

This problem came up in a machine learning application, and is way out of my area but seems somewhat promising. Intuitively, the longer the mean length from $M$ to $N$, the smaller a proportion $N$ is of $M$, but I can't quantify this relationship.

Comment: So, $|M|=\sup_{x,y\in M} d(x,y)?$

Comment: What does "size" mean here? Since you are talking about geodesics these are not just metric spaces. You are clearly not talking about the cardinality (the number of points).

Comment: @EthanBolker Sorry, I don't know a better way to put it. What I mean by geodesic is the path through the points in the space that minimizes the metric, i.e distance. It might not be precise to call that a geodesic unless I'm talking about a manifold - but I don't know a better word. I am talking about the cardinality when I say "size".

Comment: @ThomasAndrews By $|M|$ I mean the number of points in $M$. I'll update accordingly

Comment: The term "Geodesic" is not used for discrete metrics. You can just say the average value if $d(x,N)$ for $x\in M,$ where $d(x,N)=\inf_{y\in N} d(x,y).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you very much. I'll update the question. Wikipedia has wronged me once again!

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts.

Absent information about the distribution of distances among the pairs of points of $M$ I don't think there is much you can conclude.

Suppose $M$ consisted of very many points distributed uniformly at random over the unit square (say). Then for any moderately large uniformly distributed subset $N$ the average value of $d(x,N)$ would be about the same, independent of the size of $N$.

For small closely packed clusters $N$ the average value of $d(x,N)$ would increase with the distance of $N$ from the center of the square, again independent of the size of $N$.

Even knowing more about $M$ I think the same kind of arguments may apply.  You can use subsets $N$ with the same approximate distribution of distances for the first examples and small clusters for the second.